# Como ordenar e sequenciar dados de um arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, data, twitter-api

Desenvolvi um programa que guarda uma lista de ids, desse modo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas para os fins desejados, os dados deveria tomar a forma sequencial, de modo que, o primeiro par de ids seja algo como: "889926212541448192" torna-se 1 e "889919950248448000" torna-se 2. Ou seja, o arquivo a ser obtido deveria ser algo como:

[image: Exemplo]

Onde o primeiro id se conecta com 2,3 e 6, e o id 4 só com o 5, formando uma rede.

Eu não tenho experiência nessa área, mas não encontro uma maneira de fazer essa leitura.

Tentei fazer alguns programas, mas eles leem apenas linha e não coluna id a id. Esses dados são salvos seguindo o seguinte programa

import json

arq = open('ids.csv','w')
arq.write('Source'+','+'Target')
arq.write("\n")

lista_rede = [] #lista para guardar todos os ids

with open('dados_twitter.json', 'r') as f:

```
for line in f:
    lista = []

    tweet = json.loads(line) # reescreve como um dicionário Python 
    lista = list(tweet.keys()) #escreve lista das chaves 

    try:
        if 'retweeted_status' in lista:
            id_rt = json.dumps(tweet['retweeted_status']['id_str'])
            id_status = json.dumps(tweet['id_str'])

            lista_rede.append(tweet['id_str'])
            lista_rede.append(tweet['retweeted_status']['id_str'])

            arq.write( id_status +','+ id_rt )
            arq.write("\n")

        if tweet['quoted_status'] in lista :
            id_rt = json.dumps(tweet['quoted_status']['id_str'])
            id_status = json.dumps(tweet['id_str'])

            lista_rede.append(tweet['id_str'])
            lista_rede.append(tweet['quoted_status']['id_str'])

            arq.write( id_status +','+ id_rt )
            arq.write("\n")
    except:
           continue
```

arq.close()

Como resultado tenho um arquivo com os dados de ids em pares de interações

Como posso então reorganizar esses dados na leitura, ou até na forma de escrevê-los?? Em python ou em outra linguagem?

Comment: Por favor, não coloque os códigos como imagem, o site possui suporte para os mesmos. Edite a pergunta e insirá-los corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pergunta um tanto confusa,e ter colado o código ao invés de printar também ajudaria...enfim,se entendi corretamente você quer que cada ID seja substituído por um número correspondente,incrementando uma unidade a cada novo ID.Fiz uma função que toma como argumento uma lista e a retorna desta forma.Segue:

```
def muda_ids(lista):
    antigos_ids = []
    for linha in lista:
        ids = linha.split(',')
        for id in ids:
            if id not in antigos_ids:
                antigos_ids.append(id)
    for cont in range(len(antigos_ids)):
        lista = [w.replace(antigos_ids[cont], str(cont)) for w in lista]
    return lista
```

Por exemplo,ao passar como argumento a seguinte lista:

```
['100,110', '100,200', '300,154', '400,156', '100,110']
```

A função retorna:

```
['0,1', '0,2', '3,4', '5,6', '0,1']
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ajudou muito, reescrevi o forma como eu criava o arquivo para criar uma lista que na forma como você fez o exemplo e usei essa função replace, como não sou da área não sabia do poder dela e está sendo real importância. Irei escrever um arquivo agora com essa nova lista. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada,fico feliz em poder ajudar :) Caso esteja satisfeito com a resposta,marque-a como aceita